# multimedia support in liferay portal

Tags: liferay, multimedia

I am new to liferay portal.. Does it supports multimedia file formats by default.. or any plugins needs to be added..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload any content to the document library - this can be files of any type. There are also plugins available to (for example) embed flash or videos on the page - these might as well come from external locations, but don't need to.

The portal itself is agnostic: It just generates the HTML, therefor everything that you can generate in HTML (and referenced files: images, css, video, audio etc) is supported. There's no specialized "streaming server", delivering large multimedia files in chunks or partially, but you can still embed them by referencing an external streaming server (if this is what you need - media streaming is not the core business of a portal)

For referencing such content from the CMS it usually pays to take a look into structures and templates. These help you to separate the links to media from the generated HTML.